# Jump to start of the line in Bash's Vi mode

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, vi

I'm using Bash Vi mode (aka `set -o vi`). Still I miss the `Ctrl-A` shortcut from Emacs mode, which is very handy. Many times I'm retrieving the last command and append an echo to the beginning of the line in order to save it to a file.

Is there a convenient way to jump to the start of the line while in insert mode?

And by convenient I mean that it's accessible by two sensible buttons shortcut. So `Esc,I` is not good enough, because `Esc` is too far, and `Ctrl+[`,`I` is not good because I need to type three consecutive letters, not sleek enough.

Comment: If Esc is too far, why are you using vi mode at all? Why don't you stick with emacs mode?

Comment: If you are a vi fan, I highly suggest binding your Caps Lock key to ESC.

Comment: @mattdm, by who? by X? by bash? Unfortunately, I already have Capslock bound to the keyboard layout switch, and it's hard to find another reachable key...

Comment: Yeah, by X. If you use the keyboard layout (altgr?) switch a lot, that might be unavoidable. I use the "menu" key for that, but I really use it only infrequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key if it's not too far. Or bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>:

```
set -o vi
bind '\C-a:beginning-of-line'
```

Comment: I didn't want to walk down the slippery `bind` slope, since eventually you end up with a `.emacs` file more complex than the emacs source code, but it's certainly a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

> Many times I'm retrieving the last
>   command and append an echo to the
>   beginning of the line in order to save
>   it to a file.

An alternative is:

```
echo !!
```

Comment: Yeah, I know that. But sometimes I don't remember which one of the last 3 commands it was, so I want to see them first on the screen, or change a few parameters. Thanks.

Comment: Then do `history`, then `echo !nnn` where nnn is the history number.  If you know it was the 2nd last command, then `echo !-2` also works

Comment: @glenn, as I said: (1) I don't remember the exact number, (2) sometimes I need to edit the line lightly.